# Android - Array or for statement problem

Tags: android

I making on a app, but I have a problem with for or with a array.
When I use this code

```
Button Button[] = {(Button)findViewById(R.id.button01), (Button)findViewById(R.id.button02), (Button)findViewById(R.id.button03),(Button)findViewById(R.id.button04)};
```

...

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
  for (int i = 0; i < Button.length; i++) {
   if (Y > Button[i].getTop()+25 && Y < Button[i].getBottom()+25 && X > Button[i].getLeft() && X < Button[i].getRight()){
    LastButton = i;
    edittext.setText("id " + i);
   }
  }
break;
```

But the for statement skip the first button in the array and the second button get id 1. anyone know how I can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: What is `Button` is it a variable or the class? It's tough to see what is actually going on here.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a array with buttons.

Comment: Use another variable for that, as the name is a name of a reserved class. You can't do `Integer Integer = 4;`

Comment: Itried with SoundButton but it doesn't work either :(